# VB.net webbrowser control click radio button

Tags: vb.net

how to click the radio button for

```
<input name="years_option" value="all_years" type="radio">
```

the following code does not work. please help.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("years_option").SetAttribute("all_years", "radio")
```

Answer (score 0):

at last got the answer from another source.

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("years_option").SetAttribute("checked", True)
```